# Creating a binary variable if individual was observed in the previous year

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Let's say I have an example dataframe in the following format:

```
df <- data.frame( c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
                  c(3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1),
                  c(23,23,34,134,134,NA,45,NA,NA)
)
colnames(df) <- c("id", "year", "fte_wage")

df <- df[is.na(df$fte_wage) == FALSE,]
```

I want to create a binary variable (let's say, a column named "obs") if the individual was observed in the previous or not. I have tried the following:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- 
  df %>% 
  arrange(id, year) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(obs = ifelse((lag(year) %in% df[df$id == id,]$year & year > lag(year)), 1, 0))
```

Which generates a column of only 0 values. If I remove the second condition the code works, but then it misinterprets the lag(year) command, as it takes values from different individuals as well.

My desired output would be a dataframe in the following format:

| id | year | fte_wage | ob |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 23 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 23 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 43 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 54 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 32 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 56 | 0 |

Comment: Yes - what is the desired output? Also `rowwise()` is also a grouping function so it will overwrite the grouping on the previous line, and it groups each row on it's own, so it will just return `NA` with a `lag()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `group_by(id)` and then check if `row_number()` is `> 1` to see if it falls in repeating run or is alone.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame("id" = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
                 "year" = c(3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1),
                  "fte_wage" = c(23,23,34,134,134,NA,45,NA,NA))

df %>% 
  drop_na(fte_wage) %>% 
  arrange(id, year) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(obs = as.numeric(row_number() > 1))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>      id  year fte_wage   obs
#>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1       45     0
#> 2     1     2      134     1
#> 3     1     3       23     1
#> 4     2     2      134     0
#> 5     2     3       23     1
#> 6     3     3       34     0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using `dplyr` without grouping.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  arrange(id, year) %>% 
  mutate(obs = (lag(id, default=F) == id) * 1)
  id year fte_wage obs
1  1    1       45   0
2  1    2      134   1
3  1    3       23   1
4  2    2      134   0
5  2    3       23   1
6  3    3       34   0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `diff` in the following way:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(id, year) %>%
  mutate(obs = +(c(0, diff(year)) == 1L))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
     id  year fte_wage   obs
  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1       45     0
2     1     2      134     1
3     1     3       23     1
4     2     2      134     0
5     2     3       23     1
6     3     3       34     0
```